# Interpretation of Unused Scale Factor Exponents

Tags: cosmology, universe

Within the Lambda-CDM model, the evolution of different "constituents" (Wikipedia calls these "species", I have no idea what the correct term is) of the universe is related to the scale factor $a$, representing the time since the Big Bang.

Because of the expansion of the universe over time, the density of radiation scales proportionally to $a^{-4}$ (due to the expansion of volume plus redshift over time), matter with $a^{-3}$ (by only volume expansion) and dark energy by $a^0$ (due to the assumption of being constant across space).

The pattern-monkey in my brain saw this and immediately asked itself: Are there any thoughts or ideas about constituents of our universe that scale with the "missing" exponents of $a^{-1}$ and $a^{-2}$?

While scaling with space and time, only space and being constant are somewhat intuitive, linear and quadratic scaling seem to be significantly more abstract. The only thing that came to mind for me was information/entropy by $a^{-2}$ (probably due to the association with the holographic principle), but I would love to hear if this is something that has been speculated about somewhere.

Comment: *pattern-monkey* Why are you not also asking about $a^1$, $a^2$, $a^3$, … and $a^{-5}$, $a^{-6}$, $a^{-7}$, … ?

Comment: If you have thoughts about any of these other exponents I'd be definitely interested as well. But I guess it feels more natural to me to "fill the gap" rather than extend the series.

Comment: My own opinion is that there is no reason to expect the gaps to be filled.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely the most sensible position and as far as I can tell, there seem to be no "serious" scientific proposals for what I'm asking. I mostly found it an interesting thought, not least to build somewhat of an intuition for what it could mean to scale linear or quadratically with our universe's age.